# Ruby on Rails - Bootstrap / Form_for vs input_groups - How to stop styles butting heads

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm playing around with some of the input boxes for my rails project.

I'm a bit taken with the first example [given here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). I like the little '@' notch and could use that for a formatting prompt to our users.

Their code looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

If i put that into my rails view it works perfectly and looks great.

But my form setup is running with a form_for function, and I'm having difficutly getting the two to play nicely.

My rails html.erb code looks like this below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
    <%= form_for @request do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :user_id%>
      <%= f.text_field :user_id%>
      <%= f.submit "Begin my request", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried wrapping the two pieces of code together in various ways but to no effect!

General constants is that my rails code always comes out with hard rectangular edges (compared to the bootstrap smooth curves), I cannot get the input-group-addon to sit comfortably on the end of the input field, it variously rides above and below or sits awkwardly over the larger form block etc... so fail on my part. Anyone got any insight?

In terms of gems pertinent to bootstrap I'm using:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.0.beta1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are running into is `form_for` is using the rails `FormBuilder` to generate your form and the method `text_field` is translating to a specific piece of html. You can have it create a different piece of html by creating your own form builder. If you opt to use another gem like `simple_form` it gets even easier as you can just create additional types of fields. You can look over the documentation for that gem for more information.

```
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def text_field_with_addon(name, addon, *args)
    @template.content_tag(:div,
      @template.content_tag(:span, addon, class: 'input-group-addon') +
      @template.text_field(name, *args),
      class: 'input-group')
  end
end
```

Then use it like:

```
<%= form_for @request, builder: CustomFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.label :user_id%>
  <%= f.text_field_with_addon :user_id, '@' %>
  <%= f.submit "Begin my request", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```